# Terraform validate disagrees with terraform docs

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have configured an `aws_cloudwatch_log_metric_filter` using Terraform:

```
// Monitor log.error() occurences in each lambda
// A metric filter watches CloudWatch logs and filters them based on patterns and expressions. 
resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_metric_filter" "log_errors" {
  name = "${local.fullname}-log-errors"

  # Look in the log group for each Lambda
  log_group_name = "/aws/lambda/${local.fullname}"

  # https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/FilterAndPatternSyntax.html
  pattern = "{ $._logLevel = \"error\" }"

  # Creates a CloudWatch metric (a numerical output) to publish the monitored log information into
  metric_transformation {
    name = "${local.fullname}-error-count"
    // The destination namespace of the CloudWatch metric.
    // (metric namespaces starting with AWS/ are reserved for AWS)
    namespace = "MyApp"
    value     = "1"
    unit      = "Count"
  }
}
```

```
$ terraform validate -no-color
  
  Error: Unsupported argument
  
    on .terraform/modules/route_lambda/api-gateway-lambda-route/alerts.tf line 112, in resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_metric_filter" "log_errors":
   112:     unit      = "Count"
  
  An argument named "unit" is not expected here.
```

line 112 is the `unit` in the `aws_cloudwatch_log_metric_filter` above.

But per the [terraform docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cloudwatch_metric_alarm#unit)

> The metric_transformation block supports the following arguments:
>
> ...
>
> unit - (Optional) The unit to assign to the metric. If you omit this, the unit is set as None.

This is hard to judge as terraform (the tool) and terraform (the docs) disagree with each other.

**Is there something wrong with my Terraform configuration or not?**

Comment: What AWS provider version are you using? `unit` was adding in 3.46.0: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/pull/19804

Comment: Thanks @ydaetskcoR. I can't upgrade right now (as we have many lambdas using the same tfstate bucket. and I'd need to upgrade them all to ensure `tfstate --init upgrade` doesn't make a tfstate that some of them can't read) but I'm pretty sure this is the correct solution. Do you want to add it as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`unit` parameter](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cloudwatch_metric_alarm#unit) of [the `aws_cloudwatch_log_metric_filter` resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cloudwatch_metric_alarm) was added in [this pull request](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/pull/19804) which was then merged and [released as part of v3.46.0](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#3460-june-17-2021).

If you're running an earlier AWS provider you'll need to update to a more recent version. In modern versions of Terraform (0.14+) you can do this by checking that you don't have any version constraints running [`terraform init -upgrade`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/init.html#upgrade-1) to upgrade the providers to the latest allowed by any version constraints.